# Send a token to another app and then validate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There are two separate django projects, So I want both are generating tokens with the same user_id, secret key and same HS256 algorithm and then once Project B sends request along with token, the token should be decrypted and the required response should be send back from Project A. How do I go forward and implement it. Should i use JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom authentication.

It can work like this:

Check header for a token and if there is not any then the user is not authenticated.

If there is a token, then send a request to project A with the token and ask if the token is valid and if it is, what is the user.

Then set get the data in project B and do what ever you want.

It's like how frontend frameworks like react and ... works.

You can use any external resources to check if a token is valid or ...

[Check here for custom authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with an oauth2 provider and 2 django apps.
Take a look here:

https://github.com/DimitrisBovasianos/CustomOauth2Authorization

You have to create a custom authentication backend and a custom  middleware to handle the refresh token in case you want to use token based authentication.

Comment: I am using ldap for authentication in both the applications

Comment: My doubt is should i create a token when he/she logs in and once request comes in verify the token in the request and the one in current app?

Comment: If i were you i wouldn't have the same authentication in both apps.I would have it in one app ( that would serve let's say as a  backend ) and create the tokens and in the other one i would make a custom authentication that would sent the data to the first one for verification and the creation of the token.Even though i haven't used ldap before I think that would work in any type o 3rd party authentication backend.